# MongoDB retrieve only specific data

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have collection like this:

```
{
  "Post": {
    "post": "These are following example of your station of the various stamps, and this can't be foured by the name.\n\n          also I can't use this way to search string in the midle way, also what are you doing is the default factory",
    "like": [
      "rudi",
      "tabootie",
      "oknoorap",
      "various",
      "rusian_roulette"
    ],
    "Comment": [
      {
        "comment_id": 1,
        "name": "Anonymous",
        "comment": "You are absolutely right dude, when you call me, you can host here",
        "like": [
          "rudi",
          "stumble",
          "upon",
          "facebook"
        ]
        "timestamp": {
          "t": 9000,
          "i": 1311245225
        }
      },
      {
        "comment_id": 2,
        "name": "Anonymous",
        "comment": "the guy is here",
        "like": [
          "rudi",
          "stumble",
          "upon",
          "facebook"
        ]
        "timestamp": {
          "t": 10000,
          "i": 1311245225
        }
      },
      {
        "comment_id": 2,
        "name": "Oknoorap",
        "comment": "the other guy is here",
        "like": [
          "rudi",
          "stumble",
          "upon",
          "facebook"
        ]
        "timestamp": {
          "t": 11000,
          "i": 1311245225
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Could you help me? How to retrieve only for Post.Comment.comment_id = 2, negation for _id, post, etc

Comment: If there is a dupe here then please post the link instead of speculating that there might be one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve only parts of an array. You can limit fetching only per document/embedded document.

Comment: You mean, that's the cons of mongodb?

doh, it's annoying me

Comment: Has nothing to do with mongo really. Your schema is not correct for what you're trying to do. Having big ever growing documents means mongo will have to move it around constantly as well. Just because you can embed documents doesn't mean you always should. Make posts a seperate collection.

Comment: OK thanks for your suggestion. Since mongodb is not relational, it's annoying me to build schema that maintainability than relational db like mysql

Comment: Yes it takes a bit of getting used to. Put your query requirements on paper and then check if they are possible using your schema. If they're not, change the schema. It's okay to have more than one collection here.

Comment: Every database has its restrictions and certain way to do data modeling..don't expect that MongoDB can help you with any trash data stored within it....

Answer (score 0):

Java or Javascript?

Java:

```
//Query items
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("Post.Comment.comment_id", 2);

//Show items
BasicDBObject showField = new BasicDBObject();
showField.put("post", 1); //show
showField.put("other", 0); //hide

//Execute query
DBCursor cursor = dbc.find(query, showField);

......
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although your document schema could probably be improved .. the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2 enables some new flexibility.

Note: you have two comments with comment_id = 2 in your example, which seems to be a mistake if you are using this to uniquely identify a comment.  I'm assuming your third comment_id should actually be comment_id = 3.

Here is a commented example using `aggregate()`:

```
db.posts.aggregate(

    // Find specific post
    { $match : {
        '_id' : 123,
    }},

    // Unwind the Post.Comment array into a stream of documents
    { $unwind : '$Post.Comment' },

    // Match specific comment_id
    { $match : {
        'Post.Comment.comment_id' : 2,
    }},

    // Limit results to the embedded Comment
    { $project: {
        'Post.Comment': 1
    }}
)
```

.. and the results:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 123,
            "Post" : {
                "Comment" : {
                    "comment_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "Anonymous",
                    "comment" : "the guy is here",
                    "like" : [
                        "rudi",
                        "stumble",
                        "upon",
                        "facebook"
                    ],
                    "timestamp" : {
                        "t" : 10000,
                        "i" : 1311245225
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: For a relevant blog post on schema design, see: [Designing MongoDB Schemas with Embedded, Non-Embedded and Bucket Structures](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/designing-mongodb-schemas-with-embedded-non-embedded-and-bucket-structures) on Redhat's OpenShift blog.